# NodeJS / Express: inconsistent [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT] occurring

Tags: node.js, express, http, post, http-headers

Here I have a POST method that gets called quite often.

```
app.post('/return_data', async (req, res) => {
    var response, file
    console.log("request recieved: " + req.body.room)
    await readFile('Data/'+req.body.room+'.json').then((data) => {
        console.log(data)
        return res.send(data)
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e)
    })
})
```

For some reason the response is intermittent. Sometimes it will log the following error.

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:535:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/ec2-user/dc-floorplans/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/ec2-user/dc-floorplans/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:194:10)
    at /home/ec2-user/dc-floorplans/app.js:127:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async /home/ec2-user/dc-floorplans/app.js:125:5 {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
```

When I first start my web app, usually the first POST logs an error. After refreshing the page, the data comes through as intended. There is only one response in the function and so I'm puzzled as to why this error is occurring.

I know that `readFile` works because the data is logged in `.then()`. How can it be that sometimes data is sent to the client and other times it throws an error when the exact same process is happening?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE -- FULL APP.JS:**

```
app.set('view-engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(cors())
app.use(flash())
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
app.use(methodOverride('_method'))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/', checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.render('index.ejs');
});

app.get('/login', checkNotAuthenticated, function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('login.ejs');
});

app.post('/login', checkNotAuthenticated, (req, res, next) => {
        passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
           if(err) throw err
           if(!user) return res.redirect('/login')
           req.logIn(user, (err) => {
              if(err) return next(err)
              if(info.message==process.env.DEFAULTPW) {
                  console.log("Default password detected for: " + user.email)
                  return res.redirect('/')
              }
              return res.redirect('/')

           })
  })(req, res, next)
})

app.get('/update', checkAuthenticated, (req, res, next) => {
        res.render('update.ejs')
})

app.post('/update', checkAuthenticated, async (req, res, next) => {
    if(req.body.pw1 != req.body.pw2) { res.redirect('/update') }
        if(req.body.pw2 == process.env.DEFAULTPW) { res.redirect('/update') }
        const newpw = await encrypt(req.body.pw2)
        var queryresult
        await con.query("UPDATE login SET password = \'"+newpw+"\' WHERE email = \'"+req.body.email.toLowerCase()+"\'", (err, result, fields) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
                return res.redirect('/update')
            };
                console.log(result)
        queryresult = result
                if(result.changedRows == 0) {
                    return res.redirect('/update')
                }

        })
        return res.redirect('/')
    });

app.post('/get_new_data', async (req, res)  => {

        console.log("New Data:")
    await pollLM(req.body.room).then((data) => {
        console.log(data)
        return res.send(data)
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e)
    })
})

async function pollLM(room) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const getData = pySpawn('python3.7', ['getData.py', room])
        getData.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        resolve(data)
        })
    })
}

app.post('/return_data', async (req, res) => {

    console.log("request recieved: " + req.body.room)
    await readFile('Data/'+req.body.room+'.json').then((data) => {
        console.log(data)
        return res.send(data)
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e)
    })
})

async function readFile(path) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile(path, (err, data) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            console.log(typeof(data))
            resolve(data)
        })
    })
}

app.post('/update_reload_time', (req, res) => {
    console.log("reload time updated to: " + req.body.time)
    fs.writeFile('Data/delay.json', JSON.stringify(req.body), () => {
        console.log("delay updated to: " + req.body.time)
    })
})

app.get('/reload_time', async (req, res) => {

    await readFile('Data/delay.json').then((data) => {
        console.log(data)
        return res.send(data)
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e)
    })
})

app.delete('/logout', (req, res) => {
    req.logOut()
    res.redirect('/login')
})

// Page routing...

function checkAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next()
    }
    res.redirect('/login')
}

function checkNotAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return res.redirect('/')
    }
    next()
}

function encrypt(text) {
    const key = crypto.scryptSync(process.env.CRYPTOPW, process.env.SALT, 24)
        const cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-192-cbc', key)

        let encrypted = ''
        cipher.on('readable', () => {
            let chunk
            while(null != (chunk = cipher.read())) {
                encrypted += chunk.toString('hex')
            }
        })

        cipher.write(text)
        cipher.end()
        return encrypted
}

function decrypt(text) {
    const key = crypto.scryptSync(process.env.CRYPTOPW, process.env.SALT, 24)
      const decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-192-cbc', key)

      let decrypted = '';
      decipher.on('readable', () => {
        while(null !== (chunk = decipher.read())) {
          decrypted += chunk.toString('utf8')
        }
      })

      const encrypted = text
      decipher.write(encrypted, 'hex')
      decipher.end()
      return decrypted
}
```

Comment: `return res.send(data)` looks like it should be fine.  I get this error when `res.end()` is called and then something is being sent.

Comment: That's the thing... it looks okay. If it was consistent I wouldn't be half as frustrated.

Comment: Can you post the contents of `data`?  Also this type of error requires non conventional debugging.  Instead of data have it return a some string and see if the error still occurs.  If it does you can rule out the contents of the variable `data`

Comment: It basically means something else is executing. This happened to me when I returned a response in my cors implementation. If you can post your index.js/server.js that would help

Comment: @Nelles The data is just standard JSON. I passed a string back and the same thing happened

Comment: @O'Dane Brissett The full file is in the original post now, cheers

Answer (score 0):

All you have to look for is where you response twice on the same call.

For example:

```
app.post('test', (req,res)=>{
 res.send('1')
 res.json('{1:2}')
})
```

will always return this error, because you are responding twice.

You have to investigate your routes one by one, I would start here:

```
app.post('/update', checkAuthenticated, async (req, res, next) => {
if(req.body.pw1 != req.body.pw2) { res.redirect('/update') }
    if(req.body.pw2 == process.env.DEFAULTPW) { res.redirect('/update') }
    const newpw = await encrypt(req.body.pw2)
    var queryresult
    await con.query("UPDATE login SET password = \'"+newpw+"\' WHERE email = \'"+req.body.email.toLowerCase()+"\'", (err, result, fields) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return res.redirect('/update')
        };
            console.log(result)
    queryresult = result
            if(result.changedRows == 0) {
                return res.redirect('/update')
            }

    })
    return res.redirect('/')
});
```

You are calling res.redirect explicitly and on condition. Have you checked if both conditions meet simultaneously? I guess here is one weak point.

And I would check this one

```
    app.post('/login', checkNotAuthenticated, (req, res, next) => {
        passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
           if(err) throw err
           if(!user) return res.redirect('/login')
           req.logIn(user, (err) => {
              if(err) return next(err)
              if(info.message==process.env.DEFAULTPW) {
                  console.log("Default password detected for: " + user.email)
                  return res.redirect('/')
              }
              return res.redirect('/')

           })
  })(req, res, next)
})
```

Again there potentially meet two conditions. Check them out. Other parts look fine to me.